# Trouble understanding fields and properties C#

Tags: c#, properties, field

I have the following line of code in my class:

```
public Vector3 HexagonSize { get; set; }
```

And then in a method I am doing this:

```
var tempSize = HexagonPrefab.GetComponentsInChildren<MeshFilter>()[0].sharedMesh.bounds.size;
HexagonSize.x = tempSize.x;
HexagonSize.y = tempSize.z; // Inverted because of blender
HexagonSize.z = tempSize.y;
```

And I am getting the exception:

```
cannot modify the return value of because it is not a variable
```

Thing is if a get rid of the property (auto-property) everything is fine.
I know how to fix the problem I have to do the following:

```
 HexagonSize = new Vector3(tempSize.x,tempSize.z,tempSize.y);
```

The question is why can I edit the values of the hexagonSize when it is a field
but I have to create a new one when it is a property. btw I know that structs are immutable

Comment: It's not that it's impossible to reassign the properties. Instead, the compiler is just warning that you probably didn't intended for it.

Comment: _"I know that structs are immutable"_ -- no, you don't know that, because not all aren't. They _should_ be, but obviously `Vector3` you're using isn't, because if it were you'd be getting a different error message (and by the way, that's a compile-time error message, _not_ an _"exception"_).